# How can I vertically space my link inside a UL and LI?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul style="float: right; margin-left: 5px;" id="status-infos">

   <li><a id="A"class="button sprite-arrow-circle" ></a></li>
   <li>
      <a id = "B" class="button">
         <img width="16" height="16" src="/Images/control-180.png">
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite-arrow-circle{ background-position: 0 0; width: 16px; height: 16px; }
.button { display: inline-block; }
.button, .form legend, .legend, .mini-menu {
   border: 1px solid white;
   border-radius: 0.417em 0.417em 0.417em 0.417em;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 1.333em;
   outline: 0 none;
   padding: 0.167em 0.5em 0.25em;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: none;
} 
a.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(/Images/sprite.png);
    background-position: 0 -396px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

The id=A link has no space above it and a large space below.

The id=B link appears vertically spaced in the center with a space above and below. This looks perfect.

Can anyone explain what might be happening. It seems only links with images in are spaced vertically in 
the correct way.

Comment: please put your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and explain, Its difficult to understand without looking at your images.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use CSS3's `background-size` property to achieve scaling with a `background-image`, CSS2 just clips backgrounds, it's how sprites work.

Comment: I added background-size: 16px 16px; to the above CSS and the image disappeared and the spacing remained the same. One thing I noticed was when I set all the a links to display: block then all the buttons move up to the top of the li. That includes id=A and id=B.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that you can link to? It's hard to diagnose without your actual images.

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/KUAm7/ I removed your `background-position: 0 -396px` and added `background-size: contain`

Comment: But I need to use the background position. I have more than ten different images in the sprite and need to be able to pick out one of the ten.

Comment: Perhaps CSS3's `background-clip` property could help too. Keep in mind, these are not supported by all browsers. And some require a prefix such as `-moz` and `-webkit`